Optimizing PostgreSQL Connection Limits on Windows Server 2019: Balancing Performance and Stability
In our production environment, we are utilizing Windows Server 2019 with 4 cores and 4 threads. Currently, PostgreSQL is configured with a maximum connection limit of 150. However, there are requirements for it to support up to approximately 160 connections. What is the recommended maximum connections per core for PostgreSQL?
Additionally, what issues might we encounter if we increase the connections beyond the suggested limit?

Who suggested 150, and what reason did they give?  Who says it requires 160, and what reason did they give?

What problem do you have? We have about 20 (very) active connections for 3 million daily customers. Not even close to 150 or 160. Just every request is lightning fast
